# Como compilar uma extensão com phpcpp usando LINKER_DEPENDECIES "-lphpcpp"?

Tags: php-cpp

Estou a compilar uma minha primeira extensão phpcpp no MacOSX Yosemite mas encontro o erro "ld: library not found for -lphpcpp" como posso resolver isso?